# Converting a string that is Big Endian to little Endian in batch script

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to convert a given string that is in Big Endian into little Endian using batch script commands ?
For example, given the string: 9295147A58EACCAA to convert it to Int32 little Endian to be: AACCEA587A149592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to change the order of characters of a string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BytesBE=%~1"
if not defined BytesBE goto :EOF

set "BytesCO=%BytesBE%"
set "BytesLE="

:ChangeOrder
set "BytesLE=%BytesLE%%BytesCO:~-2%"
set "BytesCO=%BytesCO:~0,-2%"
if defined BytesCO goto ChangeOrder

echo    Big Endian: %BytesBE%
echo Little Endian: %BytesLE%
endlocal
```

The batch file can be run with a string like `9295147A58EACCAA` from within a command prompt window to test the simple loop and see the produced output as stored in `BytesLE` from input as stored in `BytesBE`. The input string length should be even for correct result.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`